# Referencing top level modules python

Tags: python-3.x

After reading some existing answers about this topic, I still can't get my head around how this works.

I have a program that manages imports the following way

`from ...src.folder.sub_folder import file_name`

For then executing methods with

`file_name.method_name()`

This works, but the interpreter im using indicates `Attempted relative import beyond top-level package` so I wanted to instance this files the right way (For learning and also removing the annoying red indicator).

Lets say I have the following tree (This is a snippet of the actual big tree, but the idea stays the same)

```
PackageTest/
    main.py
    src/
        tasks/
            __init__.py
            tasks.py
        security/
            recon/
                __init__.py
                some_scan.py
```

With the following contents

`tasks.py`

```
def function_1():
    print("Function1")
    return

def function_2():
    print("Function2")
    return

def function_3():
    print("Function3")
    return
```

How can I reference the methods present in `tasks.py` from `some_scan.py`?

Im doing the following with no success.

`some_scan.py`

```
import src.tasks as tasks

def call_task():
    tasks.function1()

call_task()
```

Comment: Relative imports (``from ...foobar import quux``) are for *inter-package* imports. In your case, ``tasks`` and ``security`` are separate packages (unless you consider ``src`` a namespace package – unlikely and not recommended) so relative imports do not apply. You should be able to use an absolute import such as ``from tasks import tasks``, and then use ``tasks.function1``.

Comment: So in my case I should do something along the lines of `from ..tasks import tasks`?

Comment: You should do ``from tasks import tasks``, as mentioned. You should *not* do something like ``from ..<something> import <something>``.